# How to read a csv in pyspark using error_bad_line = False as we use in pandas

Tags: csv, pyspark

I am trying to read a csv into pyspark but the problem is that it has a text column due to which there are some bad line in the data

This text column also contains the new line characters due to which the data in further columns is getting corrupted

I have tried using pandas and use some extra parameters to load my csv

```
a = pd.read_csv("Mycsvname.csv",sep = '~',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, dtype = str,error_bad_lines=False, quotechar='~', lineterminator='\n' )
```

It is working fine in pandas but I want to load the csv in pyspark 
So, is there any similar way to load a csv in pyspark with all the above parameters?

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of spark (I think it is even there from spark 2.2 onwards), you can also read multi-line from csv.

If the newline is your only problem with the text column you can use a read command like this:

`spark.read.csv("YOUR_FILE_NAME", header="true", escape="\"", quote="\"", multiLine=True)`

Note: in our case the escape and quotation characters where both `"` so you  might want to edit those options with your `~` and include `sep = '~'`. 
You can also look at the documentation (http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=csv#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv) for more details